# Compiling errors during Java compiling

Tags: java

I'm slightly new to the who Java coding business and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. All of the errors seem to be "class, interface, or enum expected".

```
        switch(itemId);
        //break;

    default:
        if(c.playerRights == 3)
            Misc.println("Player used Item id: "+itemId+" with Npc id: "+npcId+" With Slot : "+slot);
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you expect this code to do?

Comment: Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 3):

Very unfortunate semi-colon. Change it to a brace. This

```
switch(itemId);
```

should be

```
switch(itemId) {
```

the semicolon terminates the code block so your `default` isn't part of the `switch` block.

Comment: Thank you for your input, managed to fix one of the errors. Suppose you've got to start somewhere, right?

Comment: @KyleHodgkiss The journey of a thousand miles begins beneath one's feet. - [Lao-Tzu](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/24004.html). But you've taken the first step.